# E-commerce, success payment redirect

Tags: php

While building e-commerce module for a friend i have encountered some problem.
Entire process is following:

- user enters site and clicks on product
- user store product into cart and click "go to checkout"
- user fills personal details such as name, address, phone number or email and click "next"
- at this point session contains all personal details of cutomer and cart content
- user clicks on one of the payment gateways like paypal and pay for his product

Each of payment gateways offer ability to redirect customer on one of the following:

- error path
- abort path
- success path

So if user successfuly payed he is redirected to `https://mydomain/payment_status?success`
which does insert to db with entire transaction details and success status so product can be send.

The problem is that everyone can put something to the cart and go straight to `https://mydomain/payment_status?success`.

We can create some safety measures like `https://mydomain/payment_status?success&transaction_code=2783j4238942j4k2m`

However it still is hardcoded and after one payment user will know the hash, as far as i know Gateway like paypal cannot generate on its own something that will tell for sure that transaction was made successfuly.

Anyone has idea how to handle that problem?

---EDIT---

Paypal form:

```
echo '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . Config::Details('email') . '">';

//Products details

echo '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' . Languages::lang_item('code') . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $this->_total . '">';
echo '<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but03.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!">';
echo '</form>';
```

Sofort form:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="https://www.sofort.com/payment/start">';
    echo '<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="' . $this->_total . '"/>';
    echo '<input name="currency_id" type="hidden" value="' . Languages::lang_item('code') . '"/>';
    echo '<input name="reason_1" type="hidden" value="' . Config::Details('reason_1') . '"/>';
    echo '<input name="reason_2" type="hidden" value="' . Config::Details('reason_2') . '"/>';
    echo '<input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="' . Config::Details('user_id') . '"/>';
    echo '<input name="project_id" type="hidden" value="' . Config::Details('project_id') . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Odesłać"/>';
echo '</form>';
```

Those are our payment gateways, and upon success - redirect is as i showed you above.
I also checked if after redirect there are any `$_POST` details provided but there are none

Comment: Just a quick search of PayPals API shows a bunch of info you can use... https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/

Comment: Doesn't success page get any `POST` data like the order id, etc.?

Comment: well ive seen api documentation but if i was able to figure out what to do on my own i wouldnt be asking would i? i posted my gateways in edit and im asking how to modify it to be able to receive correct response and how to receive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like PayPal's IPN (Instant Payment Notification) will work for you.  Have a look at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ - basically, you set up a page to listen for responses coming from PayPal.  Upon successful payment, PayPal communicates with your listener page securely so you can mark orders as paid and complete.

Comment: These are what bothers me though:

- Internet connectivity is not always 100% reliable and IPN messages can be lost or delayed

- The service resents messages for up to 4 days

- Because IPN is not a real-time service, your checkout flow should not wait for the IPN message before it is allowed to complete

- and few others

well it doesnt feel right and trust worthy, also doesnt seem like common way of doing things for most of the e-commerce sites

Comment: It is usually instant but you're right, it isn't a real-time service.  However, you can code to handle delays in responses.  You wouldn't really want to mark an order as paid until you know for a fact that the money has hit your account, so until the notification arrives you would mark the order as "in progress", or something along those lines.